# Can not load saved model in keras / tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, auto-keras

I trained the model using ***autokeras*** with ***TensorFlow 2.5.***
I saved the pre-trained model using both methods explained on Keras (TensorFlow) home page.
`model.save(f'model_auto_keras{max_trials}.h5')` `model.save("keras_test_save_model")`

again when I want to load the saved model using
`model = tf.keras.models.load_model(f'model_auto_keras{max_trials}.h5')`
and
`model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model("keras_test_save_model/")`
both methods are not doing well in my case.

saying ValueError: Unknown layer: Custom>
[ValueError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQBhp.png)

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: Custom>MultiCategoryEncoding.
Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for 
details.
```

**the main problem is Custom layer >> MultiCategoryEncoding** which is not available in keras.

[RuntimeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBFGa.png)

Answer (score 1):

@krishna
You can try:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CategoryLayerName': tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding()})
```

In your model declaration use layer name for CategoryEncoding layer.

I'm not sure if it should be tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding() or tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding